# Bringing ToolWindow to Front of Application

Tags: vb.net, vba

Basically, in my code I transform my form into a toolwindow in the load event:

```
Dim lStyleEx As Long = win32.WS._EX_TOOLWINDOW
Call SetWindowLong(Handle, win32.GWL.__EXSTYLE, CInt(lStyleEx))
Const swpFlags As Long = _
        win32.SWP._FRAMECHANGED Or _
        win32.SWP._NOMOVE Or _
        win32.SWP._NOSIZE Or _
        win32.SWP._NOZORDER
Call SetWindowPos(Handle, CType(0, IntPtr), 0, 0, 0, 0, CType(swpFlags, win32.SetWindowPosFlags))
```

(I have a class win32 containing enums for all the constants)

Now, I want to bring this toolwindow to the front with the IVsWindowFrame.Show(), but I'm having trouble getting the actual IVsWindowFrame for my form. After trawling the web I found a snippet on the MSDN forums, but after converting to VBA various issues come up, e.g. I don't know how to properly create a new ServiceProvider:

```
Dim shell As IVsUIShell = DirectCast(ServiceProvider.GetService(GetType(SVsUIShell)), IVsUIShell)
Dim frame As IVsWindowFrame
Dim guid As New Guid(ToolWindow.GuidList.guidToolWindowPersistanceString)
shell.FindToolWindow(CUInt(__VSFINDTOOLWIN.FTW_fForceCreate), guid, frame)
frame.Show()
```

Sourced from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d6c2b85c-3a48-48f7-a9f6-a68ea4ef0441/how-to-get-access-to-my-toolwindowpane-object-with-an-ivswindowframe-pointer?forum=vsx

Any help with finding the IVsUIShell of a form or an explanation on this code would be greatly appreciated!

I've also tried something as simple as setting the actual form as an IVsWindowFrame:

```
Dim windowFrame As IVsWindowFrame = CType(Me, IVsWindowFrame)
windowFrame.Show()
```

but it throws an exception:

```
type 'RifleSystem.scrSettings' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsWindowFrame'.
```

btw, I'm running 64-bit VS2013 if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I feel stupid now. There's a property Form.Owner which does exactly what I need in this scenario, and it works perfectly! No need for all this convuluted stuff :D

Here's the link in case anyone is interested:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner%28v=vs.110%29.aspx